# AutoCompleteTextView & ArrayAdapter with back to Fragment

Tags: kotlin, fragment, android-arrayadapter, lifecycle, autocompletetextview

(sorry for my english)

I have fragment where I have an `AutocompleteTextView` and `ArrayAdapter` for it.
`ArrayAdapter` get values from resource strings.

When fragment creating first time — everything is ok, but when I go to fragment back (with backstack or replace with saved fragment) my `AutocompleteTextView` show only 1 item but `ArrayAdapter` size is 6. I really don't know why is that...

I was thinking if I save `ArrayAdapter` at viewmodel it will work, but no.
I want to see my items after I back to fragment

`SomeFragment.kt` (all names changed):

```
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val mSomeViewModel = SomeViewModel()

    private lateinit var mSomeAutoCompleteTextView: AutoCompleteTextView
    private lateinit var mSomeStrings: Array<String>
    private lateinit var mSomeArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        mSomeStrings = resources.getStringArray(R.array.strings_array)
        mSomeArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, mSomeStrings)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_server, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.apply {
            mSomeAutoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.someAutoCompleteTextView)
        }

        mSomeAutoCompleteTextView.apply {
            setText(mSomeStrings[mSomeViewModel.positionId])
            /* when breakpoint here and check mSomeArrayAdapter.count there are 6 items, but app show only one */
            setAdapter(mSomeArrayAdapter)
            setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                mSomeViewModel.someFunction(position)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`SomeViewModel.kt` (all names changed):

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val positionId: Int
        get() = mPositionId

    fun someFunction(position: Int) {
        mPositionId = position

        /* some other code */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just found a solution. My mistake was that I use standard `ArrayAdapter` instead of my own (or it's because `ArrayAdapter` has something bad). I created custom `BaseAdapter` with `Filterable` and it's work.

Code if someone needed:

```
class OrderArrayAdapter<T : Any>(
    private val context: Context,
    list: Array<T>
) : BaseAdapter(), Filterable {
    private val mObjects = list

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mObjects.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return mObjects[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val item = getItem(position)
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.dropdown_item, parent, false)

        view.apply {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dropdownTextView).text = item.toString()
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return customFilter
    }

    private val customFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = mObjects
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
I extended directly from ArrayAdapter in my project and it worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens in the autocomplete edit text, when you set the text in the edit text without specifying whether to filter list data or not. By default, it keeps only one matching record and discard others, to correct your code you can replace your autocomplete code with the following

```
 mSomeAutoCompleteTextView.apply {
            setText(mSomeStrings[mSomeViewModel.positionId], false)
            setAdapter(mSomeArrayAdapter)
            setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                mSomeViewModel.someFunction(position)
            }
        }
```

Comment: hello, thank you for answer! I tried this, but it not help. I add new argument to setText like in your code but I still can choose only one item (which was selected before I go another fragment and back to this)